# Possible bug in the data.table v 10.5

Tags: r, data.table

Unfortunately you will not be able to reproduce the error because that will require posting data, which I cannot do but the error is as follows.
When I read the file in the following way:

```
for (i in 1:length(folders)){
  setwd(folders[i])
  files_to_loop<-list.vector()
  for (j in 1:length(files_to_loop){
    data_aux<-fread(files_to_loop[j],sep=",",encoding="UTF-8",header=TRUE)
  }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Parameter na.strings == <<NA>>
None of the 1 na.strings are numeric (such as '-9999').
Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open
File opened, filesize is 1.380467 GB.
Memory mapping ... ok
Detected eol as \r\n (CRLF) in that order, the Windows standard.
Positioned on line 1 starting: <<filename,ETP,ETP_code,ETP_name>>
Using supplied sep ','
  sep==','(ascii 44)  with 101 lines of 203 fields using quote rule 0
  sep==','(ascii 44)  with 433261568 lines of 1488633016 fields using quote rule 3
Error in fread(files_to_loop[j], colClasses = c("character"), sep = ",",  : 
  Internal error: first line has field count 232 but expecting 1488633016
```

Whereas if I then go back and just execute:

```
data_aux<-fread(files_to_loop[j],sep=",",encoding="UTF-8",header=TRUE)
```

Then everything is fine and the message is like this:

```
Parameter na.strings == <<NA>>
None of the 1 na.strings are numeric (such as '-9999').
Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open
File opened, filesize is 1.380467 GB.
Memory mapping ... ok
Detected eol as \r\n (CRLF) in that order, the Windows standard.
Positioned on line 1 starting: <<filename,ETP,ETP_code,ETP_name>>
Using supplied sep ','
  sep==','(ascii 44)  with 101 lines of 203 fields using quote rule 0
Detected 203 columns on line 1. This line is either column names or first data row (first 30 chars): <<filename,ETP,ETP_code,ETP_name>>
All the fields on line 1 are character fields. Treating as the column names.
```

Everything works perfectly on the version 10.4 but unfortunately there fread() is not multithreaded.

Comment: This doesn't look like a question. Maybe review guidelines here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support

Comment: @Frank did not know that we are not supposed to tell about bugs here!

Comment: You can tell about bugs here if it's part of a question that others might be able to help with... In this case, it doesn't look like it. Btw, I guess you know this but `for (i in idx) x <- f(...)` overwrites `x` in each iteration and therefore is probably useless (unless there's more to the loop).

Comment: @Frank I know I am storing everything in the list and then doing rbindlist(), it was just to illustrate the bug !